# C++ passing a member function as an argument to another member function

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I want to pass a member method as an argument to another member method. I have researched this extensively but still can not see to get it correct. My header file is as follows

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

#include "Entity.h"
#include "World.h"
#include "Item.h"

class Tile;

class Player : public Entity
{
private:
    using FunctionPointer = void (Player::*)(Tile*);
    bool victory;
    Point location;
    std::map<char, FunctionPointer> actions;

public:
    Player(std::string name, int gold, int maxHitPoints, int defensePoints, 
           Point startingLocation, int maxDamage = 0, int maxItems = -1,
           std::vector<Item*> inventory = std::vector<Item*>());

    std::string getClassName() const override;

    void printInventory(Tile*) override; 
    std::string toString() override;

    Point getLocation() const;
    Item* findMostPowerfulWeapon();
    void heal(Tile*);
    void moveNorth(Tile*);
    void moveSouth(Tile*);
    void moveEast(Tile*);
    void moveWest(Tile*);
    void attack(Tile* tile);
    void pickup(Tile* tile);
    void trade(Tile* tile);

    void getAvailableActions(Tile* tile);
    void chooseAction();

private:
    void move(int dx, int dy);
    void actionAdder(char hotkey, FunctionPointer, std::string name);
};
```

And a part of the cpp file that is giving me problems is as follows:

```
void Player::getAvailableActions(Tile * tile)
{
    actions.clear();
    std::cout << "Choose an action:" << std::endl;
    if (getInventory().size() > 0)
        actionAdder('i', (this->*(&Player::printInventory))(tile), "Print inventory");
    if (tile->getClassName() == "Trader")
        actionAdder('t', (this->*(&Player::trade))(tile) , "Trade");
    if (tile->getClassName() == "Monster")
        actionAdder('a', (this->*(&Player::attack))(tile), "Attack");
}

void Player::actionAdder(char hotkey, FunctionPointer action, std::string name)
{}
```

Visual studio marks the parenthesis in front of all three this, (this->*(&Player::attack))(tile), and gives the tool tip "argument of type "void" is incompatible with parameter of type "Player::FunctionPointer"". The compiler error that I get if I try to compile is 'void Player::actionAdder(char,Player::FunctionPointer,std::string)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'void' to 'Player::FunctionPointer'.

If anyone has any idea of what I am doing wrong I would be grateful for any suggestions. If you need to see more code or more details let me know. The code is not super secret.

Thanks

Comment: Advice -- If the issue is with member function pointers, test a simple class with two dummy functions, a member function that uses a function pointer parameter and a simple 3 or 4 line `main` program attempting to call the function.  No need for all of this code to explain the issue you're having with the concept of member function pointers.

Comment: Except I am passing a member function pointer to another function in the same class, not from main. All the examples I was able to find had what you suggested. However, this is not what I was attempting to do.

Comment: Given the answer you accepted, you do see that you could have duplicated your issue with a much smaller example?  Any C++ coding / compiler issue can be duplicated with just a few lines of code.

Comment: I do see that and I appreciate your suggestion. Sometimes with stackoverflow it is hard to know how much code to supply. I have seen examples where the person asking the question is told they did not give enough information or the ever popular "why do you even want to do that". In the future, if I have another question I will attempt to replicate the issue with a smaller amount of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the error messages carefully:

> **argument of type "`void`"** is incompatible with parameter of type

and

> cannot convert **argument 2 from '`void`'** to '`Player::FunctionPointer`'.

That's because argument 2 here:

```
actionAdder('i', (this->*(&Player::printInventory))(tile), "Print inventory");
```

is actually *invoking* `printInventory` and trying to pass the result of that invocation into `actionAdder()`. But that's a `void` function, and you can't pass something of type `void` to something else - hence the error complaining about precisely that.

You don't want to invoke `printInventory`, you just want to pass a pointer to it. That's just:

```
actionAdder('i', &Player::printInventory, "Print inventory");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got it to work using your comments and suggestions.